# Xamarin: Custom Component Error(Class not found)

Tags: c#, android, custom-component

I am trying to implement drag and re-arrange listview items in android C#. However I get a class not found error. Can somebody take a look at it and let me know what I am doing wrong?

My main XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ListViewAnimations">

<com.example.dragTest.DraggableListView
  android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Main Activity Class:

```
 protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        var list = FindViewById<DraggableListView>(Resource.Id.listview);


        items = new List<string> {
            "Vegetables",
            "Fruits",
            "Flower Buds",
            "Legumes",
            "Vegetables",
            "Fruits",
            "Flower Buds",
            "Legumes",
        };
        list.Adapter = new DraggableListAdapter (this, items);
    }
```

My Custom DraggableListView Class:

```
public class DraggableListView : ListView, ITypeEvaluator, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
{
    bool _reorderingEnabled = true;

    public bool ReorderingEnabled {
        get {
            return _reorderingEnabled;
        }
        set {
            if (!value) {
                ItemLongClick -= HandleItemLongClick;
            } else {
                ItemLongClick += HandleItemLongClick;
            }
            _reorderingEnabled = value;
        }
    }

    const int LINE_THICKNESS = 15;
    const int INVALID_ID = -1;
    const int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    int mLastEventY = -1;
    int mDownY = -1;
    int mDownX = -1;
    int mTotalOffset = 0;
    int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    bool mCellIsMobile = false;

    long mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
    long mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
    long mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;

    View mobileView;
    Rect mHoverCellCurrentBounds;
    Rect mHoverCellOriginalBounds;
    BitmapDrawable mHoverCell;
    GestureDetector dectector;

    ///
    /// Constructors
    ///
    public DraggableListView (Context context) : base (context)
    {
        init (context);
    }

    public DraggableListView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        init (context);
    }

    public DraggableListView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
    {
        init (context);
    }

    public void init (Context context)
    {
        //  the detector handles all the gestures
        dectector = new GestureDetector (this);
        ItemLongClick += HandleItemLongClick;
    }

    #region Handlers


    void HandleItemLongClick (object sender, ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Long press is handeled in the OnLongPress method of the IOnGestureListener Interface
        // for some reason we have to wire this up to detect the long press, otherwise, the gesture gets ignored
    }


    void HandleHoverAnimatorUpdate (object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate ();
    }

    void HandleHoverAnimationStart (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Enabled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Resets the global variables and visbility of the mobile view
    /// </summary>
    void HandleHoverAnimationEnd (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
        mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
        mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;
        mHoverCell = null;
        Enabled = true;
        Invalidate ();

        mobileView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IOnGestureListener Implementation

    public bool OnDown (MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the touch event was right or left swipe
    /// </summary>
    public bool OnFling (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnSingleTapUp (MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the item long click by hiding the selected view, creating the dummy view drawable and adding it to the screen
    /// </summary>
    public void OnLongPress (MotionEvent e)
    {
        mTotalOffset = 0;

        int position = PointToPosition (mDownX, mDownY);

        if (position < 0 || !LongClickable)
            return;

        int itemNum = position - FirstVisiblePosition;

        View selectedView = GetChildAt (itemNum);
        mMobileItemId = Adapter.GetItemId (position); // use this varable to keep track of which view is currently moving
        mHoverCell = GetAndAddHoverView (selectedView);
        selectedView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible; // set the visibility of the selected view to invisible

        mCellIsMobile = true;

        UpdateNeighborViewsForID (mMobileItemId);
    }

    public bool OnScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnShowPress (MotionEvent e)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Bitmap Drawable Creation

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the hover cell with the appropriate bitmap and of appropriate
    /// size. The hover cell's BitmapDrawable is drawn on top of the bitmap every
    /// single time an invalidate call is made.
    /// </summary>
    BitmapDrawable GetAndAddHoverView (View v)
    {

        int w = v.Width;
        int h = v.Height;
        int top = v.Top;
        int left = v.Left;

        Bitmap b = GetBitmapWithBorder (v);

        BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable (Resources, b);

        mHoverCellOriginalBounds = new Rect (left, top, left + w, top + h);
        mHoverCellCurrentBounds = new Rect (mHoverCellOriginalBounds);

        drawable.SetBounds (left, top, left + w, top + h);

        return drawable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a red border over the screenshot of the view passed in.
    /// </summary>
    static Bitmap GetBitmapWithBorder (View v)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = GetBitmapFromView (v);
        Canvas can = new Canvas (bitmap);

        Rect rect = new Rect (0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        Paint paint = new Paint ();
        paint.SetStyle (Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.StrokeWidth = LINE_THICKNESS;
        paint.Color = Color.Red;

        can.DrawBitmap (bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        can.DrawRect (rect, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a bitmap showing a screenshot of the view passed in
    /// </summary>
    static Bitmap GetBitmapFromView (View v)
    {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (v.Width, v.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
            v.Draw (canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        }
        return default(Bitmap);

    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores a reference to the views above and below the item currently
    /// corresponding to the hover cell. It is important to note that if this
    /// item is either at the top or bottom of the list, mAboveItemId or mBelowItemId
    /// may be invalid.
    void UpdateNeighborViewsForID (long itemID)
    {
        int position = GetPositionForID (itemID);
        mAboveItemId = Adapter.GetItemId (position - 1);
        mBelowItemId = Adapter.GetItemId (position + 1);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the view in the list corresponding to itemID 
    /// </summary>
    public View GetViewForID (long itemID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++) {
            View v = GetChildAt (i);
            int position = FirstVisiblePosition + i;
            long id = Adapter.GetItemId (position);
            if (id == itemID) {
                return v;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the position in the list corresponding to itemID
    /// </summary>
    public int GetPositionForID (long itemID)
    {
        View v = GetViewForID (itemID);
        if (v == null) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return GetPositionForView (v);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  DispatchDraw gets invoked when all the child views are about to be drawn.
    ///  By overriding this method, the hover cell (BitmapDrawable) can be drawn
    /// over the listview's items whenever the listview is redrawn.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void DispatchDraw (Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.DispatchDraw (canvas);
        if (mHoverCell != null) {
            mHoverCell.Draw (canvas);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets data related to touch events, moves the bitmap drawable to location of touch, and calls the HandleCellSwitch method to animate cell swaps
    /// </summary>
    public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
    {
        try {
            dectector.OnTouchEvent (e);
            switch (e.Action) {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                mDownX = (int)e.GetX ();
                mDownY = (int)e.GetY ();
                mActivePointerId = e.GetPointerId (0);
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                if (mActivePointerId == INVALID_POINTER_ID)
                    break;

                int pointerIndex = e.FindPointerIndex (mActivePointerId);
                mLastEventY = (int)e.GetY (pointerIndex);
                int deltaY = mLastEventY - mDownY;


                if (mCellIsMobile) { // Responsible for moving the bitmap drawable to the touch location
                    Enabled = false;

                    mHoverCellCurrentBounds.OffsetTo (mHoverCellOriginalBounds.Left,
                        mHoverCellOriginalBounds.Top + deltaY + mTotalOffset);
                    mHoverCell.SetBounds (mHoverCellCurrentBounds.Left, mHoverCellCurrentBounds.Top, mHoverCellCurrentBounds.Right, mHoverCellCurrentBounds.Bottom);
                    Invalidate ();
                    HandleCellSwitch ();
                } 
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                TouchEventsEnded ();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                TouchEventsCancelled ();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Error Processing OnTouchEvent in DynamicListView.cs - Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine ("Error Processing OnTouchEvent in DynamicListView.cs - Stacktrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return base.OnTouchEvent (e);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This Method handles the animation of the cells switching as also switches the underlying data set
    /// </summary>
    void HandleCellSwitch ()
    {
        try {
            int deltaY = mLastEventY - mDownY; // total distance moved since the last movement
            int deltaYTotal = mHoverCellOriginalBounds.Top + mTotalOffset + deltaY; // total distance moved from original long press position

            View belowView = GetViewForID (mBelowItemId); // the view currently below the mobile item
            View mobileView = GetViewForID (mMobileItemId); // the current mobile item view (this is NOT what you see moving around, thats just a dummy, this is the "invisible" cell on the list)
            View aboveView = GetViewForID (mAboveItemId); // the view currently above the mobile item

            // Detect if we have moved the drawable enough to justify a cell swap
            bool isBelow = (belowView != null) && (deltaYTotal > belowView.Top);
            bool isAbove = (aboveView != null) && (deltaYTotal < aboveView.Top);

            if (isBelow || isAbove) {

                View switchView = isBelow ? belowView : aboveView; // get the view we need to animate

                var diff = GetViewForID (mMobileItemId).Top - switchView.Top; // the difference between the top of the mobile view and top of the view we are about to switch with

                // Lets animate the view sliding into its new position. Remember: the listview cell corresponding the mobile item is invisible so it looks like 
                // the switch view is just sliding into position
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat (switchView, "TranslationY", switchView.TranslationY, switchView.TranslationY + diff);
                anim.SetDuration (100);
                anim.Start ();


                // Swap out the mobile item id
                mMobileItemId = GetPositionForView (switchView);

                // Since the mobile item id has been updated, we also need to make sure and update the above and below item ids
                UpdateNeighborViewsForID (mMobileItemId);

                // One the animation ends, we want to adjust out visiblity 
                anim.AnimationEnd += (sender, e) => {
                    // Swap the visbility of the views corresponding to the data items being swapped - since the "switchView" will become the "mobileView"
//                      mobileView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
//                      switchView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

                    // Swap the items in the data source and then NotifyDataSetChanged()
                    ((IDraggableListAdapter)Adapter).SwapItems (GetPositionForView (mobileView), GetPositionForView (switchView));
                };
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Error Switching Cells in DynamicListView.cs - Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine ("Error Switching Cells in DynamicListView.cs - Stacktrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);

        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets all the appropriate fields to a default state while also animating
    /// the hover cell back to its correct location.
    /// </summary>
    void TouchEventsEnded ()
    {
        mobileView = GetViewForID (mMobileItemId);
        if (mCellIsMobile) {
            mCellIsMobile = false;
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            ((DraggableListAdapter)Adapter).mMobileCellPosition = int.MinValue;

            mHoverCellCurrentBounds.OffsetTo (mHoverCellOriginalBounds.Left, mobileView.Top);

            ObjectAnimator hoverViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.OfObject (mHoverCell, "Bounds", this, mHoverCellCurrentBounds);
            hoverViewAnimator.Update += HandleHoverAnimatorUpdate;
            hoverViewAnimator.AnimationStart += HandleHoverAnimationStart;
            hoverViewAnimator.AnimationEnd += HandleHoverAnimationEnd;
            hoverViewAnimator.Start ();
        } else {
            TouchEventsCancelled ();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// By Implementing the ITypeEvaluator Inferface, we are able to set this as the the ITypeEvaluator for the hoverViewAnimator
    /// This method is responsible for animating the drawable to its final location after touch events end.
    /// </summary>
    public Java.Lang.Object Evaluate (float fraction, Java.Lang.Object startValue, Java.Lang.Object endValue)
    {
        var startValueRect = startValue as Rect;
        var endValueRect = endValue as Rect;

        return new Rect (Interpolate (startValueRect.Left, endValueRect.Left, fraction),
            Interpolate (startValueRect.Top, endValueRect.Top, fraction),
            Interpolate (startValueRect.Right, endValueRect.Right, fraction),
            Interpolate (startValueRect.Bottom, endValueRect.Bottom, fraction));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interpolate the specified start, end and fraction for use in the Evaluate method above for a smooth animation
    /// </summary>
    public int Interpolate (int start, int end, float fraction)
    {
        return (int)(start + fraction * (end - start));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets all the appropriate fields to a default state.
    /// Resets the visibility of the currently mobile view
    /// </summary>
    void TouchEventsCancelled ()
    {
        mobileView = GetViewForID (mMobileItemId);
        if (mCellIsMobile) {
            mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
            mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
            mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;
            mHoverCell = null;
            Invalidate ();
        }

        if (mobileView != null)
            mobileView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        Enabled = true;
        mCellIsMobile = false;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake on my package name , this should actually be my namespace which is  That solved my issue.